# How to use Notepadqq for edit git commit messages?

Tags: configuration, git, notepadqq

I found examples for Windows but I do not find for Ubuntu.

https://blog.kitware.com/using-notepad-for-your-git-commit-messages/

How to use Notepadqq for edit git commit messages in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried using the `git config` command? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

Do one of the following (not necessarily both):

- Set `core.editor` : `git config --global core.editor "notepadqq"`
- Set the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable: `export GIT_EDITOR=notepadqq`

Comment: `export` applies to the current shell session only.

Comment: I tried to do it as in the first version. But it shows me message "Aborting commit due to empty commit message." When I try to do as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725160/aborting-commit-due-to-empty-commit-message git config --global core.editor "Notepad++ -w" - it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`notepadqq` needs a way to be "openable" in a fresh session and blocking the terminal, so it does not let git finishes before you've edited your commit message or rebase task list.

I would recommend `kate` as an alternative, that works really well for that. Edit your `~/.profile` file, by adding this line

```
export GIT_EDITOR="kate --startanon --block"
```